# How to get unique of unhashable list in python

Tags: python

I have a list of items below.

```
a=[['JR06-C5-p21'], ['JR06-C5-p21'], ['JR06-C5-p21'], ['JR06-C5-p21'], ['JR06-C5-p21'], ['JR06-C5-p21'], ['JR06-C5-p21'], ['JR06-C5-p21'], ['JR06-C5-p21'], ['JR06-C5-p21'], ['JR06-C5-p21'], ['JR06-C5-p21'], ['JR06-C5-p21'], ['JR06-C5-p21'], ['JR06-C5-p21'], ['JR06-C5-p21'], ['JR08-C2-p20'], ['JR08-C2-p20'], ['JR08-C2-p20'], ['JR08-C2-p20'], ['JR08-C2-p20']]
```

When I tried to get unique of a as `list(set(a))`, I get `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`. How do I get the solution for this?

Comment: `list(set([i[0] for i in a]))`

Comment: I want to make sure you understand WHY you got this.  You do not have a list of strings.  You have a list of lists.  Because lists can be modified, they cannot be stored in a set.  Changing the list would screw up the set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't care about the order, you could convert the data to a hashable type, create a set, and then convert back to lists.

```
a = [
    ['JR06-C5-p21'], ['JR06-C5-p21'], ['JR06-C5-p21'], ['JR06-C5-p21'],
    ['JR06-C5-p21'], ['JR06-C5-p21'], ['JR06-C5-p21'], ['JR06-C5-p21'],
    ['JR06-C5-p21'], ['JR06-C5-p21'], ['JR06-C5-p21'], ['JR06-C5-p21'],
    ['JR06-C5-p21'], ['JR06-C5-p21'], ['JR06-C5-p21'], ['JR06-C5-p21'],
    ['JR08-C2-p20'], ['JR08-C2-p20'], ['JR08-C2-p20'], ['JR08-C2-p20'],
    ['JR08-C2-p20']
]

a = list(map(list, set(map(tuple, a))))
print(a)
```

```
[['JR08-C2-p20'], ['JR06-C5-p21']]
```

If insertion order matters, you can do a similar trick as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-i-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-while-preserving-order), with the adaptation that you still transform the inner data to a hashable type:

```
def filter_unique(seq):
    seen = set()
    return [
        x for x in seq
        if not ((hashable := tuple(x)) in seen or seen.add(hashable))
    ]


print(filter_unique(a))
```

```
[['JR06-C5-p21'], ['JR08-C2-p20']]
```

Comment: `if not ((hashable := tuple(x)) in seen or seen.add(hashable))` just use a for loop

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yeah, I was just trying not to edit the original code too much where I borrowed that from. Would probably do this with a for loop and have the function be a generator. Then the user can choose what final container type they want explicitly.